# Terraform RDS Option group options are keeps re-applying the same changes with dynamic block

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

I have a Terraform RDS Code, i am Using Dynamic Blocks with For each, when i do terraform plan the option group options are re-applying each time. Can some one please help me? i think it is a Bug,

Can someone please help me?

```
main.tf

resource "aws_db_option_group" "without_s3_integration" {
  #count = "${var.enable_s3_integration == false ? 1 : 0}"

  name                     = lower("${var.db_name}-${formatdate("YYYY-MM-DD-hhmm", timestamp())}-og")
  option_group_description = format("Option group for %s", var.db_name)
  engine_name              = var.engine_name
  major_engine_version     = var.major_engine_version

  option {
    option_name = "Timezone"

    option_settings {
      name  = "TIME_ZONE"
      value = "US/Eastern"
    }
  }

  dynamic "option" {
    #for_each = var.option_group_add_sqlt == false ? [] : [var.option_group_add_sqlt]
    for_each = range(var.option_group_add_sqlt == true ? 1 : 0)

    content {
      option_name = "SQLT"

      option_settings {
        name  = "LICENSE_PACK"
        value = "T"
      }
    }
  }
```

```
variable.tf

variable "option_group_add_sqlt"{
  description = "Add SQLT to option group"
  type        = bool
  default     = true
}
variable "option_group_add_utlmail"{
  description = "Add utlmail to option group"
  type        = bool
  default     = true
}
variable "option_group_add_oem"{
  description = "Add oem to option group"
  type        = bool
  default     = false
}
variable "enable_s3_integration"{
  description = "Indicates if S3 integration should be turned on or not"
  type        = bool
  default     = true
}
```

```
terraform plan

  # aws_db_option_group.without_s3_integration will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_db_option_group" "without_s3_integration" {
        id                       = "rajtest4-2021-05-13-1621-og"
        name                     = "rajtest4-2021-05-13-1621-og"
        tags                     = {
            "Author" = "Effectual Terraform script"
            "Date"   = "2021-05-13T16:21:54Z"
        }
        # (4 unchanged attributes hidden)

      - option {
          - db_security_group_memberships  = [] -> null
          - option_name                    = "S3_INTEGRATION" -> null
          - port                           = 0 -> null
          - version                        = "1.0" -> null
          - vpc_security_group_memberships = [] -> null
        }
      + option {
          + db_security_group_memberships  = []
          + option_name                    = "S3_INTEGRATION"
          + version                        = "1.0"
          + vpc_security_group_memberships = []
        }
      - option {
          - db_security_group_memberships  = [] -> null
          - option_name                    = "SQLT" -> null
          - port                           = 0 -> null
          - version                        = "2018-07-25.v1" -> null
          - vpc_security_group_memberships = [] -> null

          - option_settings {
              - name  = "LICENSE_PACK" -> null
              - value = "T" -> null
            }
        }
      + option {
          + db_security_group_memberships  = []
          + option_name                    = "SQLT"
          + vpc_security_group_memberships = []

          + option_settings {
              + name  = "LICENSE_PACK"
              + value = "T"
            }
        }
      - option {
          - db_security_group_memberships  = [] -> null
          - option_name                    = "Timezone" -> null
          - port                           = 0 -> null
          - vpc_security_group_memberships = [] -> null

          - option_settings {
              - name  = "TIME_ZONE" -> null
              - value = "US/Eastern" -> null
            }
        }
      + option {
          + db_security_group_memberships  = []
          + option_name                    = "Timezone"
          + vpc_security_group_memberships = []

          + option_settings {
              + name  = "TIME_ZONE"
              + value = "US/Eastern"
            }
        }
      + option {
          + db_security_group_memberships  = []
          + option_name                    = "UTL_MAIL"
          + vpc_security_group_memberships = []
        }
    }

Plan: 0 to add, 2 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

i am not sure why it is deleting adding the options.  When i do terraform plan after terraform apply. it should not do any changes rite since i did not add anything extra, why terraform is always adding the resources and deleting it? is there any way to prevent happening like this?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue today. Analyzing the plan, I can check that the only change was in the version field of the S3_INTEGRATION option

So, I update my code from this:

```
option {
    option_name = "S3_INTEGRATION"
}
```

To this

```
option {
    option_name = "S3_INTEGRATION"
    version     = "1.0"
}
```